# mongodb find if hierarch exists

Tags: mongodb

With given below example

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot" }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron" }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "Dan", "reportsTo" : "Andrew" }
```

can I find whether "Dan" reports to "Ron". Here "Ron" is not immediate parent of "Dan" ? For this query, I should get empty response
For a query whether "Dan" reports to "Eliot", I should get the hierarchy between "Dan" and "Eliot" which obviously includes "Andrew"

I tried $graphlook where we are able to use "$match" for beginning the hierarchy. But dont know upto which level the query should run. I cannot hardcode "maxDepth"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not possible during query time without using an `$aggregation`, which constructs the hierarchy for all documents. (Very slow)

Instead I'd suggest you store the hierarchy on every document:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "name" : "Dev" }
{ "_id" : 2, "name" : "Eliot", "reportsTo" : "Dev", reportChain: [1] }
{ "_id" : 3, "name" : "Ron", "reportsTo" : "Eliot", reportChain: [2, 1] }
{ "_id" : 4, "name" : "Andrew", "reportsTo" : "Eliot", reportChain: [2, 1] }
{ "_id" : 5, "name" : "Asya", "reportsTo" : "Ron", reportChain: [3, 2, 1] }
{ "_id" : 6, "name" : "Dan", "reportsTo" : "Andrew", reportChain: [4, 2, 1] }
```

This extra field makes your use-case possible and reads fast.
But you need to maintain it whenever creating, updating, deleting a document.

Comment: Thanks. In my case the hierarchy gets built-up dynamically. I will not be knowing upfront the hierarchy.